# Using variables in an @include block in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have this mixin:

```
@mixin mobile {
  @media (max-width: 576px) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to do the following:

```
height: calc($image_height - $spacing_between_items);
```

But the variables don't get evaluated. I think it might be because of how `@content` works, but I'm not a SASS expert.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the way `@content` works but the way `calc()` works. You have to [interpolate](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) the variables within the `calc()` function:

```
$image_height: 100%;
$spacing_between_items: 10px;

@include mobile {
  .class {
    height: calc(#{$image_height} - #{$spacing_between_items}});
  }
}
```

Outputs:

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .class {
    height: calc(100% - 10px});
  }
}
```

Comment: To OP: On a side note, if the variables hold a fixed value, you don't need calc either.

Comment: Ok, now I get a different error. `$image_height` is in %, while `$spacing_between_items` is in px. This works fine in Chrome, but it appears that SASS can't handle that?

Comment: Oh, I see. I just need to interpolate both vars separately :)